# Problem Updating Ubuntu 20.04 to Kernel 5.15

Tags: kernel

After signing and upgrading my kernel to 5.15 on Ubuntu Server 20.04, everything boots fine. It drops me into a shell login and after a few moments I'm flooded with this error.

```
bpfilter: read error 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly did you update the kernel?

Comment: Downloaded from the ppa mainline.
Then sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: The mainline kernel is not considered stable and should only be used for testing purposes. I suggest that you revert the changes that you made. See: [Ubuntu Wiki Mainline Builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).  If you wish to continue testing an unsupported kernel, please [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so that developers can identify and fix these issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links.

Comment: Yes, some are having troubles with bpfilter issues. Myself, I have not been able to re-create the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to fix this issue. If you disable `bpfilter` and `ufw` (Ubuntu firewall) as follows, the `dmesg` command does not display the error messages (e.g. `bpfilter: read error 0`).

1. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
2. Add:

   ```
   blacklist bpfilter
   ```
3. Save and close `vi` by pressing: `:wq` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Then run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo ufw status 
   sudo ufw disable 
   sudo ufw status
   ```

Some system info:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux 5.15.2-051502-generic #202111121041 SMP Fri Nov 12 16:26:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
```